# Python/Tkinter - How Would I Make a Window More "Important" Than Other Application Windows

Tags: python, tkinter, window, foreground

I'd like to know how I can have my window as a priority over other application windows.

For instance, even if my window was on top of an existing application window, and I happened to click on the existing application window, I don't want my window to hide behind the existing window, I want it to stay visible (in the foreground) at all times. Is this possible?

(Using overrideredirect, by the way)

Comment: This is probably going to be system specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows you can use `topmost`

```
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
```